# Tingle Statues | Respawning source of 100 Rupees

Tags: wii-u, zelda-wind-waker

In the Gamecube version of Wind Waker, didn't the Tingle Statues serve another purpose, hinting to the location of a respawning source of 100 Rupees?

Do they still do that in the **WiiU HD version**? Because I went through the trouble of getting them all only to realize I had no idea whether or not they still did that...

Answer (score 5):

Yes. They do the same thing they did in the GameCube version. 
[Here's a link (all puns intended)](http://www.zelda-sanctuary.net/legend-of-zelda-series/the-wind-waker-hd/tingle-statues/)